# escape quotes javascript string coming from page parameters

Tags: visualforce, javascript, parameters

I got a bit stuck on this little problem. I have a page that get's it's parameters from a layout button(url & formula). I need to use the parameters inside javascript ( angular). My problem is that some account's may have either single or double quotes which gives me "unexpected token errors". 
So my question is : how can assign the passed parameters inside the javascript.

```
 var someObj ={accountLabel:"{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accountLabel}"}
```

thanks

Comment: Could you clarify, how you navigate to the Vf page. If that's from a custom button then with javascript onclick you could pass your data in the url and then you just need to parse the url using javascript ( angular in your case ). I had one scenario where in my accout details page for a related list with a custom button. I used to pass account id through url via javascript onclick on that button, then navigate to Vf page and then parse that url to get account id in javascript.

Comment: there is a custom button on tha page layout that redirects to a url /apex/myPage?accountLabel={!object__c.Account_Name__c}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this doc for other functions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

> **JSENCODE**  Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by
>   inserting escape characters, such as a backslash (), before unsafe
>   JavaScript characters, such as the apostrophe (').    {!JSENCODE(text)}
>   and replace text with the merge field or text string that contains the
>   unsafe JavaScript characters.

Try (Not tested)

```
 var someObj ={accountLabel:"{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.accountLabel)}"}
```

Comment: tested and it works I thought the characters would be displayed escaped but they look normal. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
{!JSINHTMLENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.accountLabel)}
```